# Preprocessor directive is ignored after publishing my ASP.NET MVC4 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, c-preprocessor

In my ASP.NET MVC4 application I use preprocessor directives as some of the code is shared between several projects. For example:

```
#if Manager2

#else
            if(TSetupBase.Database.SystemDatabase.IsSetup && value == CommunicationStatus.Successful)
                SysDirManager.SaveSysdirValue(SYS_DIR_LAST_COMM_KEY, TConverting.GetCurrentDT().ToString(BaseFormatUtils.DateTimeDBFormat)); ;
#endif
```

This is in a class library whose compilation symbols are:
[image]

Therefore, the code after the #else should not be run. This is what happens when we are running the program on our development machines, however, after we have published the program to our server this code runs, which causes exceptions.
Does anyone know why this is so? We have tried to research this problem but to no avail. Thanks

Comment: Make sure you define those directives in your release build configuration.

Comment: Thanks dhackman, that fixed it.